# assign NA to specific Row

Tags: r, na

I have an embarassing question:

I can not assign NAs to specific row

```
    #I will be using the Hitters dataset
    Hitters[,2] = Hitters[1:5,2] <- NA
```

But then all rows in my second column is changed to NA rather than only the 1 to 5th row. I know that it is a stupid question, but hopefully someone has a very easy solution to it. Thanks

Comment: Just chop out the first part: `Hitters[1:5, 2] <- NA`

Comment: @wow..just got myself a prize for asking the most stupid question. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @BoroDega Don't worry. It's not easy to take the cake in terms of bad questions; the bar is set quite high - or low, depending on the perspective. I've seen much worse on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it almost right but a small edit required. You need to use a list of rows which you're not
So correct code is

Hitters[c(1:5), 2] <- NA